# How to Show appropriate form When Clicking Tree view child node in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have Tree view that have 2 Root(Masters, Transactions) node and Each Root have 1 Child([See Tree view in Image](https://gyazo.com/fcba1ebeff5702feb077ccb6818c66c8))

> Masters->Party master
>
> Transactions->Order Acceptance

I want to Display `frmPartymaster.vb` form when clicking Party Master(child node)
and
Display `frmorder.vb` form when clicking Order Acceptance(child node)

I Tried Tree view After Select event(see below code)

```
 Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    For Each node As TreeNode In Me.TreeView1.Nodes
        GetChildren(node)
    Next node
End Sub

Function GetChildren(ByVal parentNode As TreeNode) As List(Of String)
    Dim nodes As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    GetAllChildren(parentNode, nodes)
    Return nodes
End Function

Sub GetAllChildren(ByVal parentNode As TreeNode, ByVal nodes As List(Of String))
    For Each childNode As TreeNode In parentNode.Nodes
        nodes.Add(childNode.Text)
        GetAllChildren(childNode, nodes)
    Next
End Sub
```

Above Code returns all childnode's names in `Return nodes` variable

Now I am Looking for

- how to use `nodes` variable values
- And how to show appropriate form when clicking child
  node(I know child node haven't click event)
- Tell me any other efficient way found instead of `afterselect` event
  because it loop through all root node and child node each time

Comment: You dont need any of that besides the `AfterSelect` method. Why dont you check the node in the afterselect, what ever it is start a new instance of your form for that node... Theres also BeforeSelect you can use as well.

Comment: @Codexer I m very new to vb.net can you explain with code ?

Comment: @Codexer Note: We can't get child node name in afterselect event or other event

Comment: Look specifically at the `Node` member of the `TreeViewEventArgs` argument to your `AfterSelect` handler.  This will give you the node that was just selected.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you provided, you are not even trying to instantiate another class depending on what node you have selected. All that is doing is adding nodes to a list, this is not needed...

This solution you can add ***any*** class where its type is `Form`.

There are a few ways this can be accomplished, but I just provided one way to do what you would like to achieve.

```
Imports System.Reflection


Public Class Form1

Private Const FORM_PARTY_MASTER As String = "frmPartyMaster"
Private Const FORM_ORDER As String = "frmorder"


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim mNode As New TreeNode With {.Text = "Masters"}
    mNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode With {.Text = "Party Masters", .Tag = FORM_PARTY_MASTER})

    Dim transNode As New TreeNode With {.Text = "Transaction"}
    transNode.Nodes.Add(New TreeNode With {.Text = "Order/Acceptance", .Tag = FORM_ORDER})

    TreeView1.Nodes.AddRange({mNode, transNode})

End Sub

Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    Dim obj As Form        
    Try
        If e.Node.Tag IsNot Nothing Then
            obj = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("WindowsApplication5." & e.Node.Tag.ToString, False)), Form)
            If obj IsNot Nothing Then
                Using obj
                    obj.ShowDialog()
                End Using
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'handle your exception
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

**Explanation**

1. Create some constants that would represent your forms.
2. The load routine was just to populate the data. You will notice I use the `Tag` property of the `TreeNode`, we will use this to get an instance of what form we would need.
3. The `AfterSelect` event is used. You will see how I create an instance of whatever control you would need; no case or if statements.
4. Make sure you change `WindowsApplication5` to what your namespace would be.